# quartz scheduler crontrigger with minutes "0/15" and hours "11-15" - when does this end?

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

Given a Quartz Scheduler CronTrigger expression like "0 0/15 11-15 ? * MON-FRI", how is that parsed?

I am correct in assuming the 11-15 does not mean "between 11 and 15" but "when the hour is 11-15, inclusive" - i.e. the expression will trigger every 15 minutes starting at 11:00 and ending at 15:45? Or will it end at 14:45? Or maybe 15:00?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Quartz documentation](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger), the "-" modifier is inclusive (for both the start and end values):

> "-" used to specify ranges. For example, "10-12" in the hour field means "the hours 10, 11 and 12".

Also, the explanation of this example expression points to the same conclusion:

> 0 0-5 14 * * ?    Fire every minute starting at 2pm and ending at 2:05pm, every day

The hours should match 15 as well, and since 0/15 will still be in effect for the hour 15, the last execution will be 15:45.

Answer (score 1):

@minodudd - Yeah... except it means the "11-15" is inclusive and after that it uses "0/15" to mean every 15 minutes so it runs until 15:45.

I left it running and it did in fact run until 15:45. This seems to be how cron expressions are interpreted in general.